# Java String manipulation

Tags: java

I have a string

`String a = "/home/eric/workspace/" + file;`

`file` can be any variable. I'ts a directory. How can i get the `/home/eric/workspace/` substring from the above?

Comment: Your question is very confusing. What exactly do you want to achieve? Get a substring from a string? Get the parent folder of a directory? Something else entirely?

Comment: You need to explain what part of the String you want to get -- the last component of the path? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `File` class:

```
String a = "/home/eric/workspace/" + someVar;
File f = new File(a);
String parentdir = f.getParent();
```

Answer (score 3):

String path =  a.substring(0, a.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

Answer (score 0):

Other alternative:

```
String a = "/home/eric/workspace/File";
String variable = "File";
String result = a.substring( 0, a. length() - variable.length() );
```

Comment: if variable is known, then you could do `path = a.replace(variable,"");`